# Get a list of database names in combobox items property

Tags: delphi

How can I populate comboboxes items property with database names (*.mdb) residing in my applicaton.exe directory at runtime ?

Comment: See [Delphi7, create combobox items](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16496352/576719) how to populate a combobox with items at runtime.

Comment: See [list all files from a directory in a string grid with delphi](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11489680/576719) how to fill a `TStrings` list with files from a directory.

Comment: I had something like this in mind :procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
databases:TStringList;
i:integer;
path:string;
begin
path:=ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + '*.mdb';
databases:=TStringList.Create;
try
for i:=0 to databases.Count-1 do
combobox1.Items.Add(databases[i]);
finally
databases.free;
end;
end;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [TDirectory.GetFiles](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Seattle/en/DirectoriesAndFilesEnumeraion_(Delphi)) function to enumerate all *.mdb files and store the result inside a [TStringDynArray](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.Types.TStringDynArray). Loop through the results and insert the values into a combobox. Make sure you include the **System.IOUtils** and **System.Types** units.

```
var
  I: Integer;
  MyList: TStringDynArray;
begin
  MyList := TDirectory.GetFiles(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)), '*.mdb',
    TSearchOption.soAllDirectories);
  for I := 0 to Length(MyList) - 1 do
  begin
    ComboBox1.Items.Add(MyList[I]);
  end;
end;
```

To insert only the file names without the path use:

```
ComboBox1.Items.Add(ExtractFileName(MyList[I]));
```